# Bladeテンプレートで変数を設定したい

Tags: php, laravel, twig

Twigテンプレートだと以下のように変数を設定できますが、Bladeテンプレートで同様の事はできるでしょうか？

```
{% set foo = 'foo' %}
{% set foo = [1, 2] %}
{% set foo = {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bladeでは変数の設定をすることはできませんが、phpを使って以下のように変数を設定し、Bladeで参照することができます。

```
<?php $var = 'test'; ?>
{{$var}}
```

参考サイト
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/256/assigning-a-variable-in-a-blade-template

Answer (score 1):

php使いたくなかったら

```
{{''; $var = 'test'}}
```

も可能です。

それはあんまり良くなかったら、macros.phpに下記を追加したら

```
{? $var= 'test' ?}
```

も出来るようになります。

```
Blade::extend(function ($value) {
return preg_replace('/\{\?(.+?)\?\}/', '<?php ${1} ?>', $value);
});
```